# Making the user enter twice in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want to increase how many times a user can use number 2, for example I want a user to enter number 2 and get the day names, and can enter again without the program ending and having to run it again.

```
Scanner i =new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter number 2 to get week day names (7)");

int day = i.nextInt();

switch (day) {
    case 1:System.out.println("Nothing");


            break;

    case 2:System.out.println("1- Saturday 2- Sunday 3- Monday 4- Tuesday 5- Wednesday 6- Thursday 7- Friday");

            break;

    default:System.out.println("You can't get any day names if you entered any number different than 2, for example: 3. ");


}


}
```

Is there anything I can add to this simple code? Thanks.

Comment: put switch case in a loop

Comment: Like for loop? Or while? I don't know which one to use and thanks for replying

Comment: you can use any one you just have to know when to break the loop otherwise you will have infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add it into a [`do-while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop, for example:

```
do {
    //Your switch here and add your scanner code here too.
} while (day != 3);
```

You might want to change your switch to something like this:

```
switch (day) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Nothing");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("1- Saturday 2- Sunday 3- Monday 4- Tuesday 5- Wednesday 6- Thursday 7- Friday");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Exit");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("You can't get any day names if you entered any number different than 3, for example: 4. ");
}
```

This way, you give the user the option to exit the program while entering a `3`.

For more information about the `do-while` loop, check the link provided above (I highly recommend you to read it).

So, after that, your code should look like:

```
Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
int day;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter number 2 to get week day names (7)");
    day = i.nextInt(); //This fixes infinite loop, you missed to read everytime you entered the loop.
    //Your switch here
} while (day != 3);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort to correct me, but I got into an infinite loop

Comment: Just don't call me sir please, makes me feel old :P I'm glad to help, btw don't forget to check the link about do-while to understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

put your switch statements inside do-while loop and declare a String variable choice. If choice == Y/y then repeat.

Comment: Thank you for anwesring.